# vertical UIToolbar (similer to BOA and Mint)

Tags: ios, ipad, toolbar, vertical-alignment, uitoolbar

I am working on application which needs to have vertical toolbar simmiler to "Bank of America" & "Mint" apps.

Can someone please guide me how to achive this?